# How to use WPF Bing Map as DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, bing-maps

Using the Bing Maps WPF-SDK it is esy to integrate a map. But I would like to use the Bing-Map as DataTemplate for an ItemsControl element. If I do so, unfortunately, the maps object does not react to any bindings and it obviously does not accept the Credentials Key. My code is as follows:

```
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:Point}">
                <ContentControl                         
                    Width="{Binding Width, Mode=TwoWay}"                    
                    Height="{Binding Height, Mode=TwoWay}"                                            
                    Template="{StaticResource InteractiveItemTemplate}">
                    <m:Map Margin="5"  ZoomLevel="5" CredentialsProvider="MyCredentials" />
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Even the ZoomLevel of 5 is not used, the map is always in default view and it displays the "Invalid Credentials" message. How to use the map in a DataTemplate properly

Comment: Should be possible.  Your binding is probably wrong.

Comment: @mdm20: which binding to you mean? The map in the code above comes always in default view. I solved it by creating a UserControl containing the map, etc. and using it as DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so my own answer is: it seems not to work if one adds the code above directly in the MainViewWindow.xaml. But once I created an separate UserControl.xaml with the Map, I than use the `UserControl` as `DataTemplate` it works well.